# JQuery function

Tags: jquery

Okay so I think tonight brain is not working, as second question of the hour!  I have the following code:

```
function merge_ts(){
    var arr = $.unique(css_ts('bookings'));
    var dai = $.unique(css_ts('diary'));

    $.each(arr, function(index, bid) { 
        $("input[type='hidden'][class^='bookings'][value=" + bid + "]").parent('div').css({'background-color':'#00008b','border-color':'#ffffff #00008b #ffffff #00008b','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
        $("input[type='hidden'][class^='bookings'][value=" + bid + "]:first").parent('div').css({'border-color':'#ffffff #00008b #ffffff #ffffff','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
        $("input[type='hidden'][class^='bookings'][value=" + bid + "]:last").parent('div').css({'border-color':'#ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #00008b','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
    });

    $.each(dai, function(index, bid) { 
        $("input[type='hidden'][class^='diary'][value=" + bid + "]").parent('div').css({'background-color':'#950404','border-color':'#ffffff #950404 #ffffff #95040','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
        $("input[type='hidden'][class^='diary'][value=" + bid + "]:first").parent('div').css({'border-color':'#ffffff #950404 #ffffff #ffffff','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
        $("input[type='hidden'][class^='diary'][value=" + bid + "]:last").parent('div').css({'border-color':'#ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #950404','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
    });
}
```

The code finds inputs that match a class and then applies styling to the all those elements, then applies styling to the first and last elements in the group.

The code currently does this for two classes, I have eight classes each with a different color, my question is to find a way of doing this without writing out the code eight times.

Comment: I say, don't hardcode styles in to javascript! Put them in a separate CSS class and then just add/remove the classes with jquery, code will look much much cleaner.

Comment: I normally do use seperate CSS class, but I have eight different classes, each with three options, so would require 24 css classes, is that cleaner?

Comment: Think of the future when you will have to maintain the code. I don't think that there are any good excuses to mix up logic - style with javascript, everything has it's own place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bite the bullet and use classes. More lines doesn't mean the solution is worse if those lines can later be read and understood in context. It's a good idea to write your code assuming someone else (or you in the distant future) will have to read it. And something like this:

```
.major-head {
  background-color: #00008b;
  border-color: #ffffff #00008b #ffffff #00008b;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
}
```

...will make a lot more sense than this:

```
{'background-color':'#00008b','border-color':'#ffffff #00008b #ffffff #00008b','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'}
```

You can also consolidate your selectors a bit. Something like this is a bit clearer (and nominally faster):

```
$.each(arr, function(index, bid) { 
  var $obj = $("input[type='hidden'][class^='bookings'][value=" + bid + "]"); 
  $obj.parent('div').addClass('major-head');
  $obj.filter(':first').parent('div').addClass('something-else');
  $obj.filter(':last').parent('div').addClass('another-thing');
}
```

If the css writing becomes really tedious, you might look into something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that is repeated in a function, and use parameter for the values that differ:

```
function merge_ts(){
  var arr = $.unique(css_ts('bookings'));
  var dai = $.unique(css_ts('diary'));

  var update = function(items, name, bg, border, firstborder, lastborder) {
    var style = {'background-color':bg,'border-color':border,'border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'};
    var first = {'border-color':firstborder,'border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'};
    var last = {'border-color':lastborder,'border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'};
    $.each(items, function(index, bid) {
      var selector = "input[type=hidden][class^=" + name + "][value=" + bid + "]";
      $(selector).parent('div').css(style);
      $(selector + ":first").parent('div').css(first);
      $(selector + ":last").parent('div').css(last);
    });
  }

  update(arr,'bookings','#00008b','#ffffff #00008b #ffffff #00008b','#ffffff #00008b #ffffff #ffffff','#ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #00008b');

  update(dai,'diary','#950404','#ffffff #950404 #ffffff #95040','#ffffff #950404 #ffffff #ffffff','#ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #950404');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it will work, haven't tested, but it should :)

```
function merge_ts(){
    var
            classes = [ //Just append this array with what you want
                {'cl' : 'bookings', 'color' : '#00008b'},
                {'cl' : 'diary', 'color' : '#950404'},
                {'cl' : '...', 'color' : '#..'},
                {'cl' : '...', 'color' : '#..'}
            ];


    $.each(classes, function(index, value){
        var
                arr = $.unique(css_ts(value.cl));

        $.each(arr, function(index, bid){
            var
                    all = $("input[type='hidden'][class^='" + value.cl + "'][value=" + bid + "]");

            all.parent('div').css({'background-color':value.color,'border-color':'#ffffff ' + value.color + ' #ffffff ' + value.color,'border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
            all.filter(":first").parent('div').css({'border-color':'#ffffff ' + value.color + ' #ffffff #ffffff','border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
            all.filter(":last").parent('div').css({'border-color':'#ffffff #ffffff #ffffff ' + value.color,'border-width':'1px 1px 0px 1px'});
        });
    });
}
```